# Pandas: sort dataframe on the basis of number of rows for the column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a    b
1    2
3    2
2    3
6    3
7    3
5    4
```

I want to sort this dataframe on the basis of number of rows for values of b
output :

```
a    b
2    3
6    3
7    3
1    2
3    2
5    4
```

any possible one liner for this ?

Comment: I've never used pandas, but is it possible to do something like `df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.rows, key=some_function), axis=0)`? (No, I have no idea why I'm trying to answer a question I know nothing about).

Comment: one liners make it so unreadable. I suggest the following 3 liner (but it's clear atleast). `df["c"] = df.groupby('b').transform(len)
df = df.sort_values("c")
df = df.drop("c",axis=1)
df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a temporary column (actually, a DataFrame with a single column, since sorting Series can cause some stable-ness problem) created based on value counts, and index the original DataFrame on the result:

```
print df.loc[df[['b']].replace(df.b.value_counts().to_dict()).sort('b', ascending=False).index]
```

Output:

```
   a  b
2  2  3
3  6  3
4  7  3
0  1  2
1  3  2
5  5  4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,2,6,7,5], 'b':[2,2,3,3,3,4]})
df.ix[df.groupby('b')[['b']].transform(len).sort('b', ascending=[0]).index]
```

---

```
    a   b
2   2   3
3   6   3
4   7   3
0   1   2
1   3   2
5   5   4
```